# Portenta pinouts for ADC

Tags: arduino-ide, pins, adc, analog-sampling, arduino-portenta-h7

I wanted to have your comments about one of my questions.

I am currently working on the sketch for the Arduino Portenta H7. However, due to my poor electrical background, I would like to ask your opinion about the pinouts.   Below you can find the pinout diagram from the document page 1 available at the below link.

https://content.arduino.cc/assets/Pinout-PortentaH7_latest.pdf

I am a bit confused about the analog pins. As the diagram and color-coding show ADC A0 ( available on the high-density connector)  and analog pin A0 both separately.   What can be the difference between them ? or maybe I am interpreting wrong.

Because, on an ordinary Arduino board ( as far as I found), we have the Analog pins which are used for the ADC too. However, here in the Portenta pinout diagram, we have ADC A0 and analog A0 separate?

I thank you for your time and opinion[image: pinouts of portenta h7].

[image: High density connectors at bottom of portenta]

Comment: it is the same pin of the MCU

Comment: Hello Juraj. Could you please elaborate a bit more, please

Comment: MCU stands for MicroController Unit. here it is the STM32H747XIH chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "high density" connectors expose every pin of the MCU. The pins around the edge of the board duplicate just the immediately useful ones.

Every pin that is on the edge of the board is also on the high density connectors somewhere.

Why have the pin on both connectors? Simple: if you want to use it in a breadboard or with jumper wires then you want the useful pins on the edge. If you want to use a plug-in board then you don't want to have to connect to both the high density connectors *and* the breadboard connectors, that would just be really awkward (since both have completely different height profiles). So everything is on the high density connectors for plug-in boards, and the useful ones are also on the breadboard headers.

A0 is the Arduino name for the pin. ADC is the function of the pin. The A of ADC stands for Analog. It's a pin that Converts Analog to Digital. It's an Analog to Digital Conversion pin - ADC.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the one pin that they marked two times as `A0`. I think they just wanted to make clear it's the same pin, maybe that people don't get confused, but in my opinion it's just more confusing.

Comment: Hello. I have added a new figure in my question. The pin marked ADC A0 is a separate pin A marked as high-density connector pin 73 of J2. So I guess probably both A0 and ADC A0 are different pins?

Comment: @BasitAli I think in the lower picture `ADC A0` is used to describe that the pin is both of it as I can't see any other `A0` description.